# Unable to style paper-date-picker when used as part of paper-date-picker-item

Tags: css, datepicker, polymer

I'm attempting to style the `date-picker-dialog` in [paper-date-picker-item](http://collaborne.github.io/paper-date-picker-item/components/paper-date-picker-item/) which makes use of `paper-date-picker` without much success. I can style the items in `paper-date-picker-item` without any issues but not the `paper-date-picker` itself.

The documentation suggests I use `paper-date-picker-dialog-style` which makes sense as I can see the import in the [source code](https://github.com/bendavis78/paper-date-picker/blob/master/paper-date-picker-dialog-style.html) but I have no experience of how this might be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these style mixins or variables within you component to override their value for instance in your compontnes style tag write:

```
<style>
    paper-date-picker-item {
        --paper-date-picker-dialog: {//mixin
            background-color: white;
        }
        --primary-text-color: green;//variable
    }
</style>
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#custom-css-properties)